# Correct XPath Syntax for this query

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<Tree>
    <Level>
        <Identity>
             <Name>FirstLevel</Name>
        </Identity>
        <Level2>
             <Data>Data1</Data>
        </Level2>
    </Level>
    <Level>
        <Identity>
             <Name>SecondLevel</Name>
        </Identity>
        <Level2>
             <Data>Data2</Data>
        </Level2>
    </Level>
    <Level>
        <Identity>
             <Name>ThirdLevel</Name>
        </Identity>
        <Level2>
             <Data>Data3</Data>
        </Level2>
    </Level>
</Tree>
```

In other words, each `Level` node has an `Identity` node with a name for it.

And I want to get the data from the `Secondlevel` > `Level2` > `Data` node.

Now, I know I can get all the `Level2` > `Data` nodes with an XPath along the lines of:

```
Tree/Level/Level2/Data
```

But to **only get the data from the SecondLevel node**, how would that syntax change?
I'm trying something like this:

```
Tree/Level[/Identity/Name='Secondlevel']/Level2/Data
```

But that's not working... How could I write this XPath and preferably as efficiently as possible?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!!!

For anyone else that would be facing this kind of issue, the correct syntax was **close** on what I thought... It was:

```
Tree/Level[Identity/Name='Secondlevel']/Level2/Data
```

... You remove the `/` from the inner specification.